# Elected moderators can nominate themselves

Tags: support, status-bydesign, election

[The second round of gaming elections has just started](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/2), and I can nominate myself again, despite having won the first round of election.

[image]

I understand this isn't going to be easy to fix, given that SE only knows about community mods, employees and developer roles, and pro-tempore mods need to be able to nominate themselves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eeeek, you've found our secret test. ):  Really this is a simple litmus test for the existing moderators.  If the election is *adding* moderators instead of *replacing* moderators and an existing moderator nominates themselves, then that's a reason to take away their diamond.  Looks like you narrowly escaped losing your diamond! (:

Comment: Then I get re-elected and get my diamond back! Right? _Right?_

Comment: *baaaaaaaaaaad π*

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jRY0L.png

Comment: @MatthewRead, win an election, then nominate yourself in the next one, and I guess we'll find out. (:

Comment: @Rebecca so now I finally know how you lost your diamond! ;)