# Are existing moderators allowed to stand in elections for reconfirmation?

Tags: support, moderators, election, nominations

A while ago, I noticed that existing moderators were re-nominating themselves for elections. In other words, the system [allows existing moderators to nominate in elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101370/elected-moderators-can-nominate-themselves) (even though they are already moderators).

In the first case I saw, it was a pro-tem election being held on a beta site: an existing pro-tem moderator had nominated in the election. In this particular case, they had nominated after receiving an email saying that they had to re-nominate (because the system assumes that the first election is after graduation, and at that point all existing moderators *do* in fact have to re-nominate), and they withdrew their nomination once it was clarified to them that the email wasn't correct.

This piqued my curiosity, though: Wikipedia [allows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Standing_reconfirmations) its administrators to stand for a "reconfirmation" nomination, going through the same procedure as a new administrator wanting to gain the tools for the first time, with the provision that they will resign as an administrator should their nomination fail. The main reason an admin would want to do this is to see if they still have the same amount of community support that they once did.

Is this allowed for Stack Exchange moderators in moderator elections? Can an existing moderator run in an election (which does not already involve existing moderators being removed), with the provision that they will only continue moderating if they win the election and resign if they don't, or will their nomination be removed? To me, it would make sense if a moderator was considering resigning or had been a moderator for a long time, and wanted to see if they still have the community support they once had.

Comment: Tangentially related: I know nitsua60 over on RPG.SE did choose to renominate himself after having previously stepped down in good standing, rather than simply going through the [reinstatement process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336175/335251). He did so essentially to ensure the community would still want him to be a mod. I know the CMs were fine with that sort of thing at the time (since I was one).

Comment: That said, the same logic wouldn't quite extend to this scenario, since it ostensibly takes up one of the open moderator slots in the election without actually electing an additional moderator. In this case, if the moderator wished to "run for reelection", then the CMs should be made aware ahead of time... Since the CMs typically decide the number of mod slots in the election depending on how many additional moderators the existing mod team feels are needed (and/or to replace existing mods who've resigned/been removed), they'd need to account for that in determining election slots.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds remarkably like a motion of confidence. As far as I understand there's no such mechanism outside sites going from beta pro tem mods to graduated regular mods.

Comment: So, SE will remove such nominations from existing moderators outside of that case?

Comment: That's not what I said.

Answer (score 4):

Every election has their aims. In case of regular election (i.e. when site is already graduated and there is no reason to nominate appointed moderators to ensure confidence from the community) that aim is increasing (for whatever reason) the number of users with diamond. Hence allowing to moderator to nominate self to elections in that case looks weird, since in case of victory they may pop another candidate (without diamond) from the winner list. But I don’t know if there are some condition in election procedure that may rely on the diamond existence from nominee. In particular such users may be excluded from the list of mod available positions. In that case nomination from the diamond looks legit.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than like an answer.

Comment: I don't think this should necessarily block a reconfirmation nomination. The team can always re-run an election with one more candidate seat (i.e. call up another nominee to meet additional demand).